# Selecting entries with nearest value less than given value

Tags: sql, oracle11g, groupwise-maximum

I want to select the entries with the nearest value less than a given value with SQL (No PL/SQL! or such thing).

I got this far:

```
select max(RUN_ID) from RUN_TABLE where KEY = 'TEST#33' and RUN_ID < 3
```

This returns the row with the highest value less than 3 matching the key but I want to be able to select all columns.

```
Run_ID  Entity  Key
1         HK    TEST#11
2         AB    TEST#22
2         CK    TEST#33
3         TB    TEST#22
3         DB    TEST#33
```

I would like to be able when having the key TEST#22 and maximal RUN_ID 4 to select the row:

```
3   TB   TEST#22
```

And when saying maximal RUN_ID 2 to retrieve

```
2   AB   TEST#22
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using? (ie mysql, sql server, postgres, oracle?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by run id descending and take only the first row, for Oracle:

```
select top 1 * from RUN_TABLE
where KEY = 'TEST#33' and RUN_ID < 3
order by RUN_ID desc
fetch first 1 rows
```

Or SQL Server (because SQLFiddle's Oracle option is down):

```
select top 1 * from RUN_TABLE
where KEY = 'TEST#33' and RUN_ID < 3
order by RUN_ID desc
```

with [live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/142f5/3).

Comment: Thanks. Great idea. For Oracle 11g you can use rownum = 1 by the way.

Comment: @Puddle "11g" is an Oracle verison, not an SqlServer version. Which are you using, Oracle or SqlServer? You comment above says SqlServer, but your version says Oracle.

Comment: Oh yes, I am using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
select Run_ID, Entity, Key from from RUN_TABLE a
where Run_ID = (select max(RUN_ID) from RUN_TABLE b where b.Key = a.Key and RUN_ID < 3)
and KEY = 'TEST#33'
```

Comment: Sounds weird but do you have an idea how it can be done without writing 'TEST#33' twice?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select t1.*
from RUN_TABLE t1
join (
   select max(RUN_ID) AS MAX_RUN_ID
   from RUN_TABLE 
   where KEY = 'TEST#33' and RUN_ID < 3
) t2 ON t1.RUN_ID = t2.MAX_RUN_ID
WHERE KEY = 'TEST#33'
```

Comment: Sounds weird but do you have an idea how it can be done without writing 'TEST#33' twice?